# Property validation in Polymer

Tags: polymer

In a *normal* JavaScript class I can use constructor and setters to ensure that my object is never passed invalid values and thus never enters an invalid state.

How would I do this in Polymer?

Here is why I am asking. I have a bug resulting from one of my component properties having an invalid value. I'm not sure how it became invalid. Normally, my first step would be to ensure that it's not being passed bad values. I would do this by using constructors and setters.

With Polymer being a layer of magic on top of Plain Old JavaScript, I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Option 1:** Create a [property observer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#change-callbacks) that logs the stacktrace (with [`console.trace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace)) when an invalid value is set. *While this option doesn't prevent the invalid value, it helps you find the bug.*

  ```html
  <head>
    <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.6.0/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-foo></x-foo>

    <dom-module id="x-foo">
      <template>
        <!-- paper-input has better methods of input validation, but this
             is intended for demonstrating property validation where the
             value can be set in any manner (not just through inputs) -->
        <paper-input label="Enter even number" value="{{foo}}"></paper-input>
        <div>valid: [[_isValid]]</div>
      </template>
      <script>
      // HTMLImports.whenReady() in index.html for demo only
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        "use strict";

        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          properties : {
            foo: {
              type: Number,
              value: 2,
              observer: '_fooChanged'
            },
            _isValid: {
              type: Boolean,
              value: false
            }
          },
          
          _fooChanged: function(foo) {
            this._isValid = foo % 2 == 0;
            if (!this._isValid) {
              console.trace('invalid value');
            }
          }
        });
      });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
  </body>
  ```

  [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/jryyzA?editors=1000)
- **Option 2:** Proxy the property through a validating [computed property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#define-a-computed-property).

  ```html
  <head>
    <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.6.0/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-foo></x-foo>

    <dom-module id="x-foo">
      <template>
        <!-- paper-input has better methods of input validation, but this
             is intended for demonstrating property validation where the
             value can be set in any manner (not just through inputs) -->
        <paper-input label="Enter even number" type="number" value="{{foo}}"></paper-input>
        <span>nearest even: [[_foo]]</span>
      </template>
      <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
        "use strict";

        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          properties : {
            foo: {
              type: Number,
              value: 2
            },
            _foo: {
              computed: '_computeEvenFoo(foo)'
            }
          },
          
          _computeEvenFoo: function(foo) {
            const num = Number(foo);
            const isValid = num % 2 == 0;
            if (!isValid) {
              console.trace('overriding invalid value');
              return num + 1;
            }
            return foo;
          }
        });
      });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
  </body>
  ```

  [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/WGRRxN?editors=1000)

In addition to (or instead of) logging the stacktrace, you could setup a breakpoint in DevTools (with [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint), [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Debugger/Debugger.html), etc.) to catch the bug as it occurs via your observer/computed property.

Comment: Here is a blog post comparing property validation in Polymer versus React: 

https://medium.com/@daveford/property-validation-in-polymer-and-react-edb446d328fd#.z9f6hp8ud